# adb: failed to check server version: cannot connect to daemon

Tags: android-studio

Hello i am facing issue try to connecting my android physical devices with android studio on mac operating system for testing my app it  was working fine few days then suddenly it gives me this issue.When i try open my mac terminal type command adb devices it will give me this issue below and i am unable connect my devices with android studio i have tried everything.uninstall android studio number of time and the reinstall it again.My usb cable is ok.Even when i test my devices using window with android studio it was working fine on window machine but on mac i am getting this issue please help me it was so frustrating for me .

Last login: Wed May 10 03:06:44 on ttys000
joshua@joshuas-MacBook-Pro ~ % adb devices

- daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
  ADB server didn't ACK
  Full server startup log: /var/folders/91/hm2yhm515qqg8wm5zzsz4dnm0000gn/T//adb.501.log
  Server had pid: 1707
  --- adb starting (pid 1707) ---
  adb I 05-10 03:09:36  1707 41532 main.cpp:63] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
  adb I 05-10 03:09:36  1707 41532 main.cpp:63] Version 34.0.1-9680074
  adb I 05-10 03:09:36  1707 41532 main.cpp:63] Installed as /Users/joshua/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
  adb I 05-10 03:09:36  1707 41532 main.cpp:63]
  adb I 05-10 03:09:36  1707 41536 usb_osx.cpp:315] reported max packet size for DEHA7PKJFIHQUSBI is 512
  adb I 05-10 03:09:36  1707 41532 auth.cpp:416] adb_auth_init...
  adb I 05-10 03:09:36  1707 41532 auth.cpp:152] loaded new key from '/Users/joshua/.android/adbkey' with fingerprint C9EB1915203476FB76DBC89FC2E5F4F5246CB85A5290D2263856992316D0AF14
  adb I 05-10 03:09:36  1707 41546 transport.cpp:335] DEHA7PKJFIHQUSBI: read thread spawning
  adb I 05-10 03:09:36  1707 41547 transport.cpp:307] DEHA7PKJFIHQUSBI: write thread spawning
  adb I 05-10 03:09:36  1707 41532 transport.cpp:1727] fetching keys for transport DEHA7PKJFIHQUSBI
  adb I 05-10 03:09:36  1707 41532 auth.cpp:468] Calling send_auth_response
  adb I 05-10 03:09:36  1707 41532 adb.cpp:176] DEHA7PKJFIHQUSBI: offline
- failed to start daemon
  adb: failed to check server version: cannot connect to daemon
  joshua@joshuas-MacBook-Pro ~

problem solving related issue just

Comment: After lot of struggling i successfully found issue was in sdk platform tool latest version in mac  used older version the issue resolved

Comment: Which version were you using and which version did you install?